# Loading Integer For The First Time Error Using NSUserdefaults Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, integer

When I got to a page with this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

//Load Upgrades

    let FourthDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var upgrades = FourthDefaults.valueForKey("Upgrades")?.integerValue
    FourthDefaults.synchronize()
    Upgrades = upgrades!
}
```

I am getting an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS error on:

```
Upgrades = upgrades!
```

In case this helps, this is my saving method.

```
let FourthDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        FourthDefaults.setObject(Upgrades, forKey: "Upgrades")
        FourthDefaults.synchronize()
```

Extra Info: This only happens when I have this code load before I save it. Otherwise it works fine.

If you know how to fix this please respond. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueForKey` returns an optional.  If there is no value for the key “upgrades”, the result will be `nil`.  This will be the case before you save the value for the first time.

This is why you have to write `valueForKey("Upgrades")?.integerValue` – because if the value returned is `nil` instead of an `AnyObject`, you can’t call `.integerValue` on it.  You have to use the `?.` operator. Read that operator as “if the result of this is `nil`, then stop and return `nil`, otherwise continue and return an optional containing the result of the next method.”

So `upgrades` is either `nil` (if there was no such key), or an optional containing the value you want.

If you force-unwrap an optional using `!`, and it is `nil`, you will get a runtime assertion, like you’re getting.  For this reason you should hardly ever use `!`.  The times you do need to use it are pretty rare and you should think carefully about whether there’s an alternative.

In this case there is a much better alternative – use the `??` operator:

```
var upgrades = FourthDefaults.valueForKey("Upgrades")?.integerValue ?? 0
```

(or whatever default value you want in the case of a missing key, if `0` isn’t it)

The `??` reads as: if the expression on the left is `nil`, then substitute the value on the right instead.  Otherwise, use the unwrapped value on the left.

This has the benefit of you not needing the `!` anymore, and should eliminate your runtime error.

Alternatively, if you want to execute different code when the value hasn’t already been set, you could write this:

```
if let upgrades = FourthDefaults.valueForKey("Upgrades")?.integerValue {
    // use upgrades, which will be unwrapped in this block
}
else {
    // handle the value not being set yet
}
```

For more on why optionals are useful, try reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622871/in-swift-how-do-i-avoid-both-optionals-and-nil-object-references/27623568#27623568).

Comment: Same as before, if you ever use `!` on a nil value, kaboom. If there is no key "money" then your `as? String` will be nil so `money!` will go bang. Use one of the techniques in my answer instead. Stop using `!` just to make it compile.