# [CLLocationCoordinate2d]? does not have a member named subscript

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, option-type

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude out of a CLLocationCOordinate2d that is in the first element of the array. I am getting an error with if let saying [CLLocationCoordinate2d]? does not have a member named subscript. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    weather.getLocationDataFromString("California USA", completion: { (location:[CLLocationCoordinate2D]?,error:NSError?) -> (Void) in
        if location != nil{
            if let coordinate = location[0] as CLLocationCoordinate2D{ // ERROR: [CLLocationCoordinate2d]? does not have a member named subscript
                println(coordinate.latitude)

        }
     }

})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an optional, so you need to unwrap it.  You're already checking for `nil` so you're almost there:

```
if let location = location {
    if let coordinate = location[0] as CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        println(coordinate.latitude)
    }
}
```

Or, perhaps nicer, if all you want is the first element:

```
if let coordinate = location?.first as? CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    println(coordinate.latitude)
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Isn't that pretty tedious to create a whole new location variable? Im not really liking this whole optionals thing with swift.

Comment: For the first one I am getting an error that says Bound value in a conditional binding must be optional type

Comment: It is a bit tedious, but only because it's forcing you to check something that, without optionals, you should also check – that is, that the result that came back from `getLocationDataFromString` is valid (it might not be), and that the array actually has a first element (it might not).  Without optionals, you could ignore these possibilities _but that would be a bad idea and lead to runtime crashes_.  Optionals just force you to do the right thing. Of course, if the context means you can be certain the optional contains a value, you can just skip the unwrap with `!`. But 99/100 you shouldn't.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27623568/3925941) for a longer explanation...

Comment: "For the first one I am getting an error that says Bound value in a conditional binding must be optional type" You get that when you have a non-optional type on the rhs of the `=`. Given `location` is definitely an optional (you declare it as such right above) I suspect a typo somewhere.

Comment: I have this: `        
        weather.getLocationDataFromString("California USA", completion: { (location:[CLLocationCoordinate2D]?,error:NSError?) -> (Void) in
            if let location = location {
                if let coordinate = location[0] as CLLocationCoordinate2D {
                    println(coordinate.latitude)
                }
            }
            
    })
` and still getting an error. I copied directly from your code

Comment: The problem is with `location[0] as CLLocationCoordinate2D `.  `as` without a question mark means "don't argue, this is an x".  `as?` means, "if this is an x, give me it in an optional, otherwise give me nil".  So because you are using `as` rather than `as?`, the result isn't optional so the `if let` binding is barfing.  Bear in mind array subscripts don't return optionals – so if you call array[0] on an empty array, you get a runtime exception.  That's why `first` is useful – it returns an optional in case the array is empty.