# Swift basic expression

Tags: swift, expression

I'm very new to swift, but proficient in other languages like Java, JavaScript, C, ... I'm lost with Swift syntax when it comes to create expressions. Look at this basic example where I just try to find out if one string is contained into another by calling `String.rangeOfString` that returns an `Optional Range` (`Range?`)

This works as expected:

```
let LEXEMA:String="http://"
let longUrl:String="http://badgirls.many/picture.png"

let range=longUrl.rangeOfString(LEXEMA);
if (range? != nil) {
   // blah
}
```

Now I'm trying to combine the expression inside the if, something like:

```
 if (longUrl.rangeOfString(LEXEMA)? !=nil) {
      // blah
 }
```

But I always get syntax errors, the above yields a "Expected Separator" and can't understand why. Done some more tests:

```
  if (absolutePath.rangeOfString(URL_LEXEMA) !=nil) { }


       Expected Separator before "!"

  if absolutePath.rangeOfString(URL_LEXEMA) !=nil { }


       Braced block of statements is an unused closure
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the exact error message output so we can give you more complete answers, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you’re coming from other like Java, you might be thinking of optionals like pointers/references, and so used to equating them to `nil` and if non-nil, using them.  But this is probably going to lead to more confusion.  Instead, think of them like a container for a possible result, that you need to unwrap to use.  `if let` combines the test and unwrapping operation.

With this in mind, here’s how you could adapt your code:

```
let LEXEMA: String="http://"
let longUrl: String="http://badgirls.many/picture.png"

if let range = longUrl.rangeOfString(LEXEMA) {
    // use range, which will be the unwrapped non-optional range
}
else {
    // no such range, perhaps log an error if this shouldn’t happen
}
```

Note, that `?` suffixing behaviour you were using changes in Swift 1.2 so even the code in your question that compiles in 1.1 won’t in 1.2.

It’s possible that sometimes you are whether there was a value returned, but you don’t actually need that value, just to know it wasn’t nil.  In that case, you can compare the value to nil without the `let`:

```
if longUrl.rangeOfString(LEXEMA) != nil {
    // there was a value, but you don't care what that value was
}
```

That said, the above is probably better expressed as:

```
if longUrl.hasPrefix(LEXEMA) { }
```

Comment: nice, makes sense! so I always have to declare intermediate variables instead of unwrapping - and - comparing in the same expression?

Comment: not always - if all you want to know is whether something is `nil`, but don’t care about _what_ the value is, then comparing it to nil works.  alternatively, if you want to know if something is equal to a value, but don’t care if it’s nil or not, just whether it’s equal to that value, then there is a version of `==` that will work too.

Comment: Here are a couple of links that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27622871/3925941 and http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/01/02/more-fun-with-implicitly-wrapped-non-optionals/

Comment: so imagine I'm on the case where I don't care what the value is, just would like to check if it's nil. Why my expression `if  longUrl.rangeOfString(LEXEMA) != nil` didn't work? btw- cool blog

Comment: it really ought to… if I cut and paste the example I just added into a playground it works OK in Xcode 6.3

Comment: hmm i'm on 6.2 maybe it's the Swift version... anyway the 'if let' construction helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For starters:

- You *don't* need parenthesis with if statements unless you have nested parenthetical subexpressions that require it.
- You *don't* need to specify the type on the left side of the `=` of a let or var declaration *if* Swift can figure it out from the right side of the `=`. Very often Swift can figure it out, and you can tell that Swift can figure it out, so you can avoid that redundant clutter.
- You *do* need to specify the type if Swift cannot figure out the type from
  the right side.  Example:

For example, consider the following lines:

```
let LEXEMA = "http://"
let longUrl = "http://badgirls.many/picture.png"
```

Swift can figure out that they're strings.

Similarly for this function or class that returns a UIView:

```
var myView = ViewReturningClassOrFunc()
```

Consider this:

```
@IBOutlet var myView : UIView!
```

In the above line, Swift cannot figure out ahead of time it will be assigned a `UIView`, so you have to provide the type. By providing a `!` at the end you've made it an *implicitly unwrapped* optional.  That means, like `?`, you're indicating that it can be `nil`, but that you are confident it will never be `nil` at the time you access it, so Swift won't require you to put a `!` after it when you reference it. That trick is a time saver and big convenience.

You should NOT add the ? to the line:

```
if (longUrl.rangeOfString(URL_LEXEMA) !=nil) {
```

As another answer pointed out, you're missing the let.

```
if let longUrl.rangeOfString(URL_LEXEMA) {
     println("What do I win? :-)")
}
```

Comment: thx for answering and valuable advice, please see my edit, still can't get it to work, I did as you tell me in last line (not adding the "?", that btw was my first attempt)

Comment: yeah it's that way, removed the println and condensed in one line for the sake of clarity here

Comment: @rupps - Dang! I knew that one. I don't know why I didn't catch that immediately. I haven't been able to work on my Swift app for several weeks, and am stuck with ugly Java at work, so that's probably why.  I've written thousands of lines of working Swift code at this point.

Answer (score 1):

swift is case sensitive language. you need to check about whitespaces as well

```
if longUrl.rangeOfString(LEXEMA) != nil { 
//your condition
}
```

there should be space between *statement != nil*

Answer (score -1):

Just add a space between `!=` and `nil` like:

```
if longUrl.rangeOfString(LEXEMA) != nil {
  // blah
}
```

I tested your code in playground, an error of **Expected ',' separator** reported.

And do not forget the rules that *1s and 0s* and *Airspeed Velocity* said.