# How do I convert a optional NSInteger to a non-optional one?

Tags: swift, option-type

I need to retrieve a setting (with Swift):

```
var highScoreNumber: NSInteger = 0
var returnValue: [NSInteger]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("food") as? [NSInteger]

if (returnValue != nil) {
    highScoreNumber = returnValue as NSInteger
}
```

I tried this and other variations of the code and I always get

> 'NSInteger?' not convertible to 'NSInteger'

This is my first foray into Swift, so

1. Am I missing something simple in the conversion?
2. Is there a better way to retrieve an NSInteger from settings?

Comment: You should use Int instead of NSInteger

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Swift, how do I avoid both optionals and nil object references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622871/in-swift-how-do-i-avoid-both-optionals-and-nil-object-references)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use NSInteger instead of Int for example?

Comment: `NSInteger` vs `Int` is irrelevant to the question being asked, but I do agree that there's no reason to use `NSInteger` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When converting a nullable value to a non-nullable one, there are [many good options to choose from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil/29717211#29717211).

But in your case, you have two issues.  One is the array you’re fetching from `NSUserDefaults` is an array of integers, so you need to decide which one you want from that array.

If it’s the first one you want, you can use the `first` property.  You can use optional chaining to get it.  And since it’s a high score, you probably want to default to zero if it’s not present.

Here’s that in one line:

```
let returnValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("food") as? [Int]

let highscore = returnValue?.first ?? 0
```

Things to note about the above: there’s no need to give the type to the left of the `=` if the type is unambiguously determined by what lies to the right of the `=`.  And it’s better to prefer `Int` over `NSInteger`.

The `returnValue?.first` says “if `returnValue` is `nil`, then `nil`, else the value of `first` (which, itself, returns `nil` if the array is empty).”  The `??` says “if the left of `??` is `nil`, then the value on the right of `nil`, else the unwrapped value from the left”.

That said – do you really mean to store an array?  Or do you really just want to store a single integer in the defaults and then get that out directly?

```
let highscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("food")
// and elsewhere in your code, when saving
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(highscore, forKey: "food")
```

(`integerForKey` already returns a 0 default when not present rather than an optional, so no need for any unwrapping)

Comment: Actually, you are right. I just want to store a single integer.