# Get rid of these Optional values

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, option-type, swift2

*Using Xcode 7 beta, Swift 2.0*

I'm saving and loading credentials to keychain, somehow when loading I get "Optional(value)" back, it looks like this is really part of the string as it also displayed like so in a textbox or when sending to API

This is how I save and load credentials now, as you see I've done a lot of extra nil checking to make sure it is not nil or Optional, it is indeed a overuse of explanation marks...

```
func SaveCredentials(credentials : [String : String!]!) -> Bool
{
    if(credentials.count == 2)
    {
        //only proceed when we have two keys:  username and password
        let username = credentials["username"]
        let password = credentials["password"]

        if let usernameStr = username
        {//also tried username!=nil && password != nil
            if let passwordStr = password
            { //usernameStr and passwordStr is of type String!
                let NsDataUsername = usernameStr!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let NsDataPassword = passwordStr!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                if(NsDataUsername != nil && NsDataPassword != nil)
                {
                    LocalStorage.saveToKeyChain("username", data: NsDataUsername!)
                    LocalStorage.saveToKeyChain("password", data: NsDataPassword!)
                    return true
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return false
}

func LoadCredentials() -> [String : String!]?
{
    let NsDataUsername = LocalStorage.loadFromKeyChain("username")
    let NsDataPassword = LocalStorage.loadFromKeyChain("password")
    if(NsDataUsername != nil && NsDataPassword != nil)
    {
        let username : String! = String(NSString(data: NsDataUsername!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        let password : String! = String(NSString(data: NsDataPassword!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        if let usernameStr = username
        {
            if let passwordStr = password
            { // password is of type String!, passwordStr is of type String
                var credentials : [String: String!] = [String : String]()
                credentials["username"] = usernameStr
                credentials["password"] = passwordStr
                return credentials
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And when I send to Api, this is my method that also requires a non-optional string. This method does work when logging in, getting strings from text fields, but does not filter out that Optional when coming from keychain.

```
func LoginUser(email : String!, password : String!)
{
    print("LoginUser(email : \(email), password: \(password))")
    var parameters = [String : AnyObject]()
    parameters["UserName"] = email
    parameters["Password"] = password
   ......
```

The strings that I send to the SaveCredentials method, are the same that the user logged in with:

```
func LoginLocalAccount(email : String!, password : String!)
{
    databaseAPI.LoginUser(email!, password: password!) //login goes just fine
    saveCredentials(email!, password: password!) //manages to get Optional in it..
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with saving and loading from keychain, for interests, [this](https://gist.github.com/s-aska/e7ad24175fb7b04f78e7) is what I use to save and load from keychain.

I want to get rid of them because when the app starts, it loads the credentials and tries to login at my API. Ofcourse I get an error back that the username is not a valid e-mail, because it is Optional(email@adress.com)

Comment: First, these are **NOT** non-optional.  They are implicitly unwrapped optionals (which are definitely optionals which can definitely be `nil`).  Second, just because `Optional(email@address.com)` *prints* with the `print` function does *not* mean that it shows up anywhere else.

Comment: But thats the problem, it does, even when I show them in the textbox again, it shows Optional

Comment: Then that's the actual value in the string.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, so my guess is, that something goes wrong when saving, any chance you can have a look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1st step is eliminating every single !. You don’t need any of them - neither the implicit optional types (should probably be non-optional, or possibly `?`) and the force-unwraps. Read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27622871/3925941) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29717210/3925941) to get a good idea of optionals and how to handle them, then rewrite your code getting rid of every instance of `!`. Once you’ve done that, you should have a better understanding of where the problem lies.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Thanks for those links, helped me to better understand the concept. This was indeed a overuse of !, no production code at all, was just figuring out where it went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overusing `!`. You don't need them. Try to learn more about implicitly unwrapped optionals, optionals, ... Your code is a mess (no offense, everybody's learning).

Back to your optional *problem*, it's caused by this line:

```
let username : String! = String(NSString(data: NsDataUsername!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

`convenience init?(data: NSData, encoding: UInt)` - inner part utilizes failable initializer, so, `NSString?` is the result. Then initialization of  `String` with optional `NSString?` produces optional as well. But, it has no sense at all do it in this way.

**First part - remove optional**

Utilizing new `guard`:

```
guard let loadedPassword = NSString(data: passwordData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
  fatalError("Ooops")
}
```

`loadedPassword` contains `NSString` (not `NSString?`) now.

**Second part - `NSString` -> `String`**

You did probably read (if not, read) [Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) about bridging, ... If you can freely exchange `NSString` with `String`, you can think that you're done:

```
var dict = [String:String]()
dict["password"] = loadedPassword
```

Nope. It produces following error:

> `NSString` is not implicitly convertible to `String`; did you mean to
>   use 'as' to explicitly convert?

Slight change and now you're done:

```
var dict = [String:String]()
dict["password"] = loadedPassword as String
```

**Complete example**

```
let password = "Hallo"
guard let passwordData = password.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
  fatalError("Ooops")
}

// save/load to/from keychain

guard let loadedPassword = NSString(data: passwordData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
  fatalError("Ooops")
}

var dict = [String:String]()
dict["password"] = loadedPassword as String

print(dict) // "[password: Hallo]\n"
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you very much, I was just optimizing my code, starting to use guard as well before saving and after loading. This was indeed a overuse of !, no production code at all, was just figuring out where it went wrong. Didn't found that error though at the NSString,