# Dictionary containing an array - Why is unwrapping necessary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to wrap my head around why what feels intuitive is illegal when it comes to a dictionary containing an array in Swift.

Suppose I have:

```
 var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
 var dict = ["a":1, "b":2, "test":arr]
```

I can easily access the dictionary members like so:

```
 dict["a"]
 dict["b"]
 dict["test"]
```

As expected, each of these will return the stored value, including the array for key "test":

> [1,2,3,4,5]

My intuitive reaction to this based on other languages is that this should be legal:

```
 dict["test"][2]
```

Which I would expect to return `3`.  Of course, this doesn't work in Swift.   After lots of tinkering I realize that this is the proper way to do this:

```
 dict["test"]!.objectAtIndex(2)
```

Realizing this, I return to my intuitive approach and say, "Well then, this should work too:"

```
 dict["test"]![2]
```

Which it does...  What I don't really get is why the unwrap isn't *implied* by the array dereference.  What am I missing in the way that Swift "thinks?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All dictionary lookups in Swift return *Optional* variables.

Why?  Because the key you are looking up might not exist.  If the key doesn't exist, the dictionary returns `nil`.  Since `nil` can be returned, the lookup type has to be an *Optional*.

Because the dictionary lookup returns an *Optional* value, you must unwrap it.  This can be done in various ways.  A safe way to deal with this is to use *Optional Chaining* combined with *Optional Binding*:

```
if let value = dict["test"]?[2] {
    print(value)
}
```

In this case, if `"test"` is not a valid key, the entire *chain* `dict["test"]?[2]` will return `nil` and the *Optional Binding* `if let` will fail so the `print` will never happen.

If you force unwrap the dictionary access, it will crash if the key does not exist:

```
dict["test"]![2] // this will crash if "test" is not a valid key
```

Comment: Nice explanation and example.

Comment: Nice! Just a side note: Another case would be, `dict["test"]!` is valid. But the array you are retrieving does not has three elements. It will also crash. @DavidHoelzer

Answer (score 1):

In the Objective-C world, it has potential crash if you are trying to access `3` by `dict[@"test"][2]`. What if `dict[@"test"]` is nil or the array you get from `dict[@"test"]` has two elements only? Of course, you already knew the data is just like that. Then, it has no problem at all.

What if the data is fetched from the backend and it has some problems with it? This will still go through the compiler but the application crashes at runtime. Users are not programmers and they only know: The app crashes. Probably, they don't want to use it anymore. So, the bottom line is: No Crashes at all.

Swift introduces a type called `Optional Type` which means value might be missing so that the codes are safe at runtime. Inside the Swift, it's actually trying to implement an `if-else` to examine whether data is missing.

For your case, I will separate two parts:

**Part 1**: `dict["test"]!` is telling compiler to ignore `if-else` statement and return the value no matter what. Instead, `dict["test"]?` will return `nil` if the value if missing. The terminology is **Explicit Unwrapping**

**Part 2**: `dict["test"]?[2]` has potential crash. What if `dict["test"]?` returns a valid array and it only has two element? This way to store the data is the same using `dict[@"test"][2]` in Objective-C. That's why it has something called **Optional Type Unwrapping**. It will only go the `if` branch when valid data is there. The safest way:

```
if let element = dict["test"]?[2] {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Dictionary`’s key-based subscript returns an optional – because the key might not be present.

The easiest way to achieve your goal is via optional chaining. This compiles:

```
dict["test"]?[2]
```

Note, though, that the result will still be optional (i.e. if there were no key `test`, then you could get `nil` back and the second subscript will not be run). So you may still have to unwrap it later. But it differs from `!` in that if the value isn’t present your program won’t crash, but rather just evaluate `nil` for the optional result.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29717210/3925941) for a long list of ways to handle optionals, or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27622871/3925941) for a bit more background on optionals.